# Can URLs containing hashtags now be used in site maps and indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap, crawlable-ajax

We are working on an Ajax application that will dynamically load content. It will be embedded in other people's site, so we were thinking of using hashtags to denote parameters for content IDs (and color scheme IDs).

Would Google be able to index this content? And could we use such URLs in a sitemap?

The reason my colleague has suggested hashtags is to avoid disrupting URLs on client sites, especially as users won't be expert developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the end of 2015 i would have recommended to implement the ajax crawling from google, but it's deprecated: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

But in general i don't recommend you to use them:

1. I'm not sure how google handels hashfragments and i found no
   trusted, fresh source
2. U can not use them with analytics (out of the box)
3. Are client side and not sent in HTTP request (for example no apache url rewrite)

If you rly want you should use Hashbangs "#!", but if you really want to build a SEO optimized page you shouldn't use them either.

Example for a SERP with Hashbangs: https://www.google.de/#q=site:anaavenue.com

Oh, and if i analyse the Google itself, the query [site:www.google.de inurl:"?q"](https://www.google.de/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1855&bih=940&q=site:www.google.de%20inurl:%22%3Fq%22&oq=site:www.google.de%20inurl:%22%3Fq%22&gs_l=hp.3...63479.63691.6.63903.2.2.0.0.0.0.139.277.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.GjJDLASB578&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.131286987,d.bGg&ech=1&psi=5jvEV7PqKourswH684Qg.1472478186072.13&ei=DTzEV43pEobvUIemuegI&emsg=NCSR&noj=1) gives me search results, but for [site:www.google.de inurl:"#q"](https://www.google.de/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1855&bih=940&noj=1&q=site%3Awww.google.de%20inurl%3A%22%23q%22&oq=site%3Awww.google.de%20inurl%3A%22%23q%22&gs_l=serp.3...26249.26436.1.26637.2.2.0.0.0.0.99.169.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.kILYR87ay5c) i don't get any.

And don't forget, that there are more search engines than Google..

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Milo. Forgive my ignorance and the following newbie question.. but what is the downside of them not being sent in HTTP request.

Comment: i think it will depend on your project, but you can't do any server side processing of the fragment. I slightly edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A sitemap is a guide to discoverable paths, not content, and such paths are to be to your site, not someone elses, so, no, don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would be a better approach. To give a little more insight, the injected content would be the client's, not ours.

Comment: @DavidNunn Remember that sitemaps are there primarily to make sure those paths are discovered when they might not be found otherwise. Search engines will find them eventually as long as there is a link somewhere to the page. If the page exists on another site, presumably they, too, have a sitemap or their page has been already discovered. I would just leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks Rob. So would Google index urls with hashtags and recognise the parameters that follow them? Egg #contentid? Grateful for confirmation on that point

Comment: I want to say they do, having read something about that recently, but Google indexes content, not URLs. Whether their search result shows the URL with a hash tag or not, I believe the answer is yes, but I just can't positively recall (cause I honestly haven't needed to care). Search results are based on content, not URLs

Comment: Many thanks. I've read different things. Google used to ignore everything after the hashtag. But as of last October it claims to be 'generally' able to crawl JavaScript sites (but not everyone is convinced). Guess the answer is to run a trial and see. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an important idea: the browser can execute JavaScript and produce content on the fly - the crawler cannot.
if you want to see, what crowlers see. you can open your page in ypur browser and  then view the source. for mor info you can see this Url:*
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

---

**that recomendation url expired. and i think this result is better and newer:** 
Google will not consider the fragments in the URLs. The answer is Google has provided a syntax for working around this problem. It’s known as the “hash bang” syntax. By putting an exclamation point immediately after the hash sign, you're telling Google that the fragments are not used for traditional scroll positioning but instead for loading separate content variations that should be crawled. With that approach, our example URLs with fragments could indeed be crawled and seen by Google. Our example URLs might then look like this:

```
www.example.com/fruits.html#!apple

www.example.com/fruits.html#!orange
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that advice now deprecated? I have seen various tests that claim Google can successfully crawl injected content (if not 100%)

Comment: That page is obsolete. [Google can crawl and process JavaScript now.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)

Comment: I modified and corrected my answer.